# Parse JSON in Map, android

Tags: android, json

How i can to get this JSON http://api.fixer.io/latest through java code and write mas "rates" in map?

Comment: it would help if you added some code - the community is more willing to help if you can show that you have done some research and if you post some code on what progress you have made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How i can to get this JSON http://api.fixer.io/latest through java code and write mas "rates" in map?

You can achieve this by using [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson), [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), and [Rxjava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava).

Here are the dependencies - build.gradle (application level):

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    project.ext {
        gsonVersion = "2.8.0"
        retrofit2Version = "2.3.0"
        okHttp3Version = "3.8.1"
        rxandroidVersion = "1.2.0"
        rxjavaVersion = "1.1.4"
    }
}
```

And in the module level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })

    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:$rootProject.ext.gsonVersion"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$rootProject.ext.okHttp3Version"
    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:$rootProject.ext.okHttp3Version"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.ext.retrofit2Version"
    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$rootProject.ext.retrofit2Version"
    compile "io.reactivex:rxandroid:$rootProject.ext.rxandroidVersion"
    compile "io.reactivex:rxjava:$rootProject.ext.rxjavaVersion"
}
```

I added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to my manifest file then I created an interface to handle getting the data from the [url](http://api.fixer.io/latest) you provided:

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;

public interface RestInterface {
    @GET("/latest")
    Call<ResultFromAPI> getJsonObjects();
}
```

First, I went to the url in my browser and I received a Json text, which I copied and pasted into [json2pojo](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/), then I made the following choices for target language, source type annotation style, etc:

[image: json2pojoimg]

Click on preview and you will see what classes you can create for the response (Json text) from the url.

Next, I created some classes to contain the response from the url:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ResultFromAPI {

    @SerializedName("base")
    @Expose
    private String base;

    @SerializedName("date")
    @Expose
    private String date;

    @SerializedName("rates")
    @Expose
    private Rates rates;

    public String getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    public void setBase(String base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Rates getRates() {
        return rates;
    }

    public void setRates(Rates rates) {
        this.rates = rates;
    }
}
```

This is the rates class:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Rates {

    @SerializedName("AUD")
    @Expose
    private Double aUD;

    @SerializedName("BGN")
    @Expose
    private Double bGN;

    @SerializedName("BRL")
    @Expose
    private Double bRL;

    @SerializedName("CAD")
    @Expose
    private Double cAD;

    @SerializedName("CHF")
    @Expose
    private Double cHF;

    @SerializedName("CNY")
    @Expose
    private Double cNY;

    @SerializedName("CZK")
    @Expose
    private Double cZK;

    @SerializedName("DKK")
    @Expose
    private Double dKK;

    @SerializedName("GBP")
    @Expose
    private Double gBP;

    @SerializedName("HKD")
    @Expose
    private Double hKD;

    @SerializedName("HRK")
    @Expose
    private Double hRK;

    @SerializedName("HUF")
    @Expose
    private Double hUF;

    @SerializedName("IDR")
    @Expose
    private Integer iDR;

    @SerializedName("ILS")
    @Expose
    private Double iLS;

    @SerializedName("INR")
    @Expose
    private Double iNR;

    @SerializedName("JPY")
    @Expose
    private Double jPY;

    @SerializedName("KRW")
    @Expose
    private Double kRW;

    @SerializedName("MXN")
    @Expose
    private Double mXN;

    @SerializedName("MYR")
    @Expose
    private Double mYR;

    @SerializedName("NOK")
    @Expose
    private Double nOK;

    @SerializedName("NZD")
    @Expose
    private Double nZD;

    @SerializedName("PHP")
    @Expose
    private Double pHP;

    @SerializedName("PLN")
    @Expose
    private Double pLN;

    @SerializedName("RON")
    @Expose
    private Double rON;

    @SerializedName("RUB")
    @Expose
    private Double rUB;

    @SerializedName("SEK")
    @Expose
    private Double sEK;

    @SerializedName("SGD")
    @Expose
    private Double sGD;

    @SerializedName("THB")
    @Expose
    private Double tHB;

    @SerializedName("TRY")
    @Expose
    private Double tRY;

    @SerializedName("USD")
    @Expose
    private Double uSD;

    @SerializedName("ZAR")
    @Expose
    private Double zAR;

    public Double getAUD() {
        return aUD;
    }

    public void setAUD(Double aUD) {
        this.aUD = aUD;
    }

    public Double getBGN() {
        return bGN;
    }

    public void setBGN(Double bGN) {
        this.bGN = bGN;
    }

    public Double getBRL() {
        return bRL;
    }

    public void setBRL(Double bRL) {
        this.bRL = bRL;
    }

    public Double getCAD() {
        return cAD;
    }

    public void setCAD(Double cAD) {
        this.cAD = cAD;
    }

    public Double getCHF() {
        return cHF;
    }

    public void setCHF(Double cHF) {
        this.cHF = cHF;
    }

    public Double getCNY() {
        return cNY;
    }

    public void setCNY(Double cNY) {
        this.cNY = cNY;
    }

    public Double getCZK() {
        return cZK;
    }

    public void setCZK(Double cZK) {
        this.cZK = cZK;
    }

    public Double getDKK() {
        return dKK;
    }

    public void setDKK(Double dKK) {
        this.dKK = dKK;
    }

    public Double getGBP() {
        return gBP;
    }

    public void setGBP(Double gBP) {
        this.gBP = gBP;
    }

    public Double getHKD() {
        return hKD;
    }

    public void setHKD(Double hKD) {
        this.hKD = hKD;
    }

    public Double getHRK() {
        return hRK;
    }

    public void setHRK(Double hRK) {
        this.hRK = hRK;
    }

    public Double getHUF() {
        return hUF;
    }

    public void setHUF(Double hUF) {
        this.hUF = hUF;
    }

    public Integer getIDR() {
        return iDR;
    }

    public void setIDR(Integer iDR) {
        this.iDR = iDR;
    }

    public Double getILS() {
        return iLS;
    }

    public void setILS(Double iLS) {
        this.iLS = iLS;
    }

    public Double getINR() {
        return iNR;
    }

    public void setINR(Double iNR) {
        this.iNR = iNR;
    }

    public Double getJPY() {
        return jPY;
    }

    public void setJPY(Double jPY) {
        this.jPY = jPY;
    }

    public Double getKRW() {
        return kRW;
    }

    public void setKRW(Double kRW) {
        this.kRW = kRW;
    }

    public Double getMXN() {
        return mXN;
    }

    public void setMXN(Double mXN) {
        this.mXN = mXN;
    }

    public Double getMYR() {
        return mYR;
    }

    public void setMYR(Double mYR) {
        this.mYR = mYR;
    }

    public Double getNOK() {
        return nOK;
    }

    public void setNOK(Double nOK) {
        this.nOK = nOK;
    }

    public Double getNZD() {
        return nZD;
    }

    public void setNZD(Double nZD) {
        this.nZD = nZD;
    }

    public Double getPHP() {
        return pHP;
    }

    public void setPHP(Double pHP) {
        this.pHP = pHP;
    }

    public Double getPLN() {
        return pLN;
    }

    public void setPLN(Double pLN) {
        this.pLN = pLN;
    }

    public Double getRON() {
        return rON;
    }

    public void setRON(Double rON) {
        this.rON = rON;
    }

    public Double getRUB() {
        return rUB;
    }

    public void setRUB(Double rUB) {
        this.rUB = rUB;
    }

    public Double getSEK() {
        return sEK;
    }

    public void setSEK(Double sEK) {
        this.sEK = sEK;
    }

    public Double getSGD() {
        return sGD;
    }

    public void setSGD(Double sGD) {
        this.sGD = sGD;
    }

    public Double getTHB() {
        return tHB;
    }

    public void setTHB(Double tHB) {
        this.tHB = tHB;
    }

    public Double getTRY() {
        return tRY;
    }

    public void setTRY(Double tRY) {
        this.tRY = tRY;
    }

    public Double getUSD() {
        return uSD;
    }

    public void setUSD(Double uSD) {
        this.uSD = uSD;
    }

    public Double getZAR() {
        return zAR;
    }

    public void setZAR(Double zAR) {
        this.zAR = zAR;
    }
}
```

Next, I created the class that will be in charge of handling the call (using the rest interface created earlier), it will also be in charge of receiving the response:

```
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.WorkerThread;
import android.util.Log;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.functions.Action1;

public class CallToFixerAPI {

    private static final String TAG = "CallToFixerAPITAG_";
    private final RestInterface restInterface;

    public CallToFixerAPI(RestInterface restInterface) {
        this.restInterface = restInterface;
    }

    @WorkerThread
    public void call(String url, final Action1<ResultFromAPI> responseAction1) throws Exception {
        try {
            Call<ResultFromAPI> call = restInterface.getJsonObjects();

            call.enqueue(new Callback<ResultFromAPI>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ResultFromAPI> call,
                                       @NonNull Response<ResultFromAPI> responseFromAPI) {
                    Observable.just(responseFromAPI.body()).subscribe(responseAction1);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ResultFromAPI> call,
                                      @NonNull Throwable t) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Failed to execute call to fixer api: " + url + ": " + e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, I tied everything together in MainActivity:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import rx.Observable;
import rx.functions.Action1;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivityTAG_";
    private CallToFixerAPI callToFixerAPI;
    private HashMap<String, Object> ratesHashMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static Map<String, Object> ConvertObjectToMap(Object obj)
            throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
        Method[] methods = obj.getClass().getMethods();

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Method m : methods) {
            if (m.getName().startsWith("get") && !m.getName().startsWith("getClass")) {
                Object value = m.invoke(obj);
                map.put(m.getName().substring(3), value);
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String url = "http://api.fixer.io/";

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RestInterface restInterface = retrofit.create(RestInterface.class);

        callToFixerAPI = new CallToFixerAPI(restInterface);

        getResponseFromAPI(url, new Action1<ResultFromAPI>() {
            @Override
            public void call(ResultFromAPI resultFromAPI) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Base is: " + resultFromAPI.getBase());
                Log.d(TAG, "Date is: " + resultFromAPI.getDate());
                try {
                    ratesHashMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) ConvertObjectToMap(resultFromAPI.getRates());
                    Log.d(TAG, "Rates are: " + ratesHashMap);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void getResponseFromAPI(String url, final Action1<ResultFromAPI> resultAction1) {
        try {
            callToFixerAPI.call(url, new Action1<ResultFromAPI>() {
                @Override
                public void call(ResultFromAPI results) {
                    Observable.just(results).subscribe(resultAction1);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I know this might seem like a lot to wrap your head around if you are new to Android or if you don't know Rxjava or Retrofit - but if you follow the steps above and can get the program to compile without any errors, you should run the app in debugger mode with several breakpoints in `MainActivity` and `CallToFixerAPI`.

I would suggest adding a breakpoint to all the `Log.d` statements and any sentence that begins with `Observable.just(...)`.

**Note**:

- I am using Android Studio 3.0 - so some things may be different from your IDE if you're not using Android Studio 3.0 as well.
- I intentionally added everything to the Logcat (Android Monitor) and nothing to the screen, the answer was getting too long. Plus, I left the decision of how best to display `ratesHashMap` to you.

Comment: That's a lot of boilerplate simply to make a web request in Android and extract some JSON values